# Python Regular Expression Index Numbers

Tags: python, regex

Just looking for some confirmation on this, but it appears that the index/position numbers for regular expressions do not follow the same rules used in the rest of python.

Example:

```
pattern=re.compile('<HTML>')
pattern.search("<HTML>")
```

output:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 6), match='<HTML>'>
```

Why is "span=(0, 6)"?

In python, the string  `"<HTML>"` is only 6 characters in length and therefore would return an index error when attempting to do something like:

```
"<HTML>"[6]
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

So I'm fairly certain the answer is that this span value for match objects is inherently different than index values for python data structures. While the span value for matched objects starts at 0 for the first character(like with all python data structures) the last character is always endpos-1.

If anyone can confirm my assumption and maybe explain why this difference exists I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm sure you are not *actually* searching through HTML with regular expressions and this is just a completely made-up example, right?

Comment: Correct, this example holds true with any matched search pattern.

Comment: Do you have a particular context in which you want to use this span numbers ?

Comment: Your assumption is correct, but I don't see it mentioned explicitly in the documentation of the `re` module.

Comment: Well lets just say that you know your pattern is 5 characters long. If you didn't realize that the rules for these indexes were different you might end up searching by doing something like pattern.search(<"HTML">,0,5). This would turn up no matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well a slice (span) in Python is open ended. So `"<HTML>and much more"[0:6]` actually returns `"<HTML>"`.

Comment: I see, so span is more like a slice than an index.

Comment: Still slightly confusing because the format it is presented in looks like an index rather than a slice. e.g (0,6) rather than [0:6].  I couldn't find anything in the doc string that explicitly stated this either.